# Extension field equality

Tags: field-theory

Suppose you have a subfield $F$ of a field $E$. If we want to prove that two extension fields are equal, e.g. $F(a) = F(b,c,d)$ for $a,b,c,d \in E$, why is it sufficient to prove that $a \in F(b,c,d)$ and $b,c,d \in F(a)$?

Comment: If $F(a)\subseteq F(b,c,d)$ and $F(b,c,d)\subseteq F(a),$ then $F(a)=F(b,c,d)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, yes that is what we want to prove, but if $a \in F(b,c,d)$, why does that translate into $F(a)$ is a subset of $F(b,c,d)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per definition, $F(b,c,d)$ is the smallest subfield of $E$ containing $F$ and the elements $b,c,d$. If $F(a)$ happens to contain $b,c,d,$ then it is *a* subfield containing $F,b,c$ and $d$.

Since it is trivial to show that $F(b,c,d)$ is the intersection of all subfields of $E$ containing $F,b,c,d,$
it follows that $F(b,c,d) \subset F(a)$.

The other inclusion follows similary.

Comment: This was a really trivial result then. Thanks for the clear explanation!

Comment: @BigMan yes, but sometimes definitions can get confusing when you first see them. You're welcome!